# Add filter return false not working

Tags: filters, hooks

simple issue but i need some help because i dont why i m wrong on this...

The apply filter (Important, this is in construct Class):

```
       if ( apply_filters( 'tc_bridge_for_woocommerce_content_order_table_is_after', true ) == true ) {
            add_action(
                'woocommerce_email_after_order_table',
                array( &$this, 'tc_add_content_email_after_order_table' ),
                99,
                4
            );
        } else {
            add_action(
                'woocommerce_email_before_order_table',
                array( &$this, 'tc_add_content_email_after_order_table' ),
                99,
                4
            );
        }
```

I need to use the false from the conditionnal

so in my functions.php from my theme

```
function filter_after_setup_theme() {
    add_filter( 'tc_bridge_for_woocommerce_content_order_table_is_after', '__return_false' ); // move info ticket in email before order details
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'filter_after_setup_theme');
```

where i m wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the filter inside of the `add_action()`, you need to call the filter directly. You have this in your functions.php file:

```
function filter_after_setup_theme() {
    add_filter( 'tc_bridge_for_woocommerce_content_order_table_is_after', '__return_false' );
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'filter_after_setup_theme');
```

You are telling to WordPress to execute the filter when the action `after_setup_theme` happens (which is called before `init` hook, according to the [Actions Hooks list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)).

Instead of the action, you should leave the filter to be registered alone, so instead of the previous code, you do this:

`add_filter( 'tc_bridge_for_woocommerce_content_order_table_is_after', '__return_false' );`

That filter will be registered in WordPress when the functions.php is loaded and not when the `add_action('after_setup_theme', 'filter_after_setup_theme');` is executed.

If you still need to execute the filter inside a hook, I recommend to do it in `init` or maybe `wp_loaded` hooks.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately with 'ini' or 'wp_loaded', it does not work too.
I will contact the author of the plugin who forgot to put this filter in his doccumentation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My bad thing is resolved (@thanks to support of Tickera)

The add_filter must be used before the loading of plugins. (with custom plugin)